# USPS - "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time."

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shipping, error, quote

I have been all over looking for a solution for this. Unfortunately, nothing I tried so far seems to work. I started receiving this error a while ago. When a customer tries to get a shipping quote in the cart, nothing is returned. When attempting a checkout (normal Magento checkout), the following is returned: "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.". I have enabled the debug option in the USPS shipping method, which yields the expected result:

```
2013-04-05T17:20:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [request] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RateV4Request USERID="XXXXX"><Revision>2</Revision><Package ID="0"><Service>PRIORITY</Service><ZipOrigination>46528</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>46506</ZipDestination><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>0.7</Ounces><Container>FLAT RATE BOX</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Machinable>true</Machinable></Package></RateV4Request>

    [result] => <?xml version="1.0"?>
<RateV4Response><Package ID="0"><ZipOrigination>46528</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>46506</ZipDestination><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>0.7</Ounces><Container>FLAT RATE BOX</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Zone>1</Zone><Postage CLASSID="17"><MailService>Priority Mail&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;amp;reg;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Medium Flat Rate Box</MailService><Rate>12.35</Rate><SpecialServices><SpecialService><ServiceID>9</ServiceID><ServiceName>Certificate of Mailing</ServiceName><Available>true</Available><AvailableOnline>false</AvailableOnline><Price>1.20</Price><PriceOnline>0</PriceOnline></SpecialService><SpecialService><ServiceID>1</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>true</Available><AvailableOnline>true</AvailableOnline><Price>1.95</Price><PriceOnline>1.95</PriceOnline><DeclaredValueRequired>true</DeclaredValueRequired><DueSenderRequired>false</DueSenderRequired></SpecialService><SpecialService><ServiceID>5</ServiceID><ServiceName>Registered Mail&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;amp;trade;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt;</ServiceName><Available>true</Available><AvailableOnline>false</AvailableOnline><Price>11.20</Price><PriceOnline>0</PriceOnline><DeclaredValueRequired>true</DeclaredValueRequired><DueSenderRequired>false</DueSenderRequired></SpecialService><SpecialService><ServiceID>4</ServiceID><ServiceName>Registered without Insurance</ServiceName><Available>true</Available><AvailableOnline>false</AvailableOnline><Price>11.20</Price><PriceOnline>0</PriceOnline></SpecialService><SpecialService><ServiceID>0</ServiceID><ServiceName>Certified Mail&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;amp;reg;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt;</ServiceName><Available>true</Available><AvailableOnline>false</AvailableOnline><Price>3.10</Price><PriceOnline>0</PriceOnline></SpecialService><SpecialService><ServiceID>13</ServiceID><ServiceName>USPS Tracking/Delivery Confirmation&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;amp;trade;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt;</ServiceName><Available>true</Available><AvailableOnline>true</AvailableOnline><Price>0.00</Price><PriceOnline>0.00</PriceOnline></SpecialService><SpecialService><ServiceID>7</ServiceID><ServiceName>Return Receipt for Merchandise</ServiceName><Available>true</Available><AvailableOnline>false</AvailableOnline><Price>4.10</Price><PriceOnline>0</PriceOnline></SpecialService><SpecialService><ServiceID>15</ServiceID><ServiceName>Signature Confirmation&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;amp;trade;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt;</ServiceName><Available>true</Available><AvailableOnline>true</AvailableOnline><Price>2.70</Price><PriceOnline>2.20</PriceOnline></SpecialService><SpecialService><ServiceID>19</ServiceID><ServiceName>Adult Signature Required</ServiceName><Available>false</Available><AvailableOnline>true</AvailableOnline><Price>0</Price><PriceOnline>4.95</PriceOnline></SpecialService><SpecialService><ServiceID>20</ServiceID><ServiceName>Adult Signature Restricted Delivery</ServiceName><Available>false</Available><AvailableOnline>true</AvailableOnline><Price>0</Price><PriceOnline>5.15</PriceOnline></SpecialService><SpecialService><ServiceID>6</ServiceID><ServiceName>Collect on Delivery</ServiceName><Available>true</Available><AvailableOnline>false</AvailableOnline><Price>6.45</Price><PriceOnline>0</PriceOnline><DeclaredValueRequired>true</DeclaredValueRequired><DueSenderRequired>true</DueSenderRequired></SpecialService></SpecialServices></Postage></Package></RateV4Response>

    [__pid] => 394
)
```

I have installed the Webshopapps_Wsausps extension, just to make sure it has nothing to do with an invalid USPS REQUEST or RESPONSE.

I also checked to make sure that the allowed countries are correct

Unfortunately neither of this help.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this turned out to be a stupid problem. I (unknowingly) switched the container size from "Variable" to "Rectangular" and that's what caused the issue. I switched it back to "Variable" and low and behold the correct rates are returned and displayed.
What threw me off was that USPS did in fact return a rate but the module did not like it and discarded it.

The error message returned to the customer is definitely misleading, especially as [Fabian Blechschmidt](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/217/fabian-blechschmidt) pointed out, the message does in fact seem to come from the PayPal module, which has absolutely nothing to do with the USPS shipping module.

Answer (score 2):

I never used this carrier, but the messages is added here:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Cart/Paypal/Mecl/Shippingmethods.php:71
```

So the question is, why is `$groups == false`?

```
$groups = $this->getShippingRateGroups();
if ($groups) {
    // ...
} else {
    $message = $this->_quote->isVirtual() ? $this->__('No shipping method required.')
        : $this->__('Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.');
        $methodListXmlObj->addCustomChild('method', null, array('label' => $message));
}
```

There is only one place I can find where the ShippingRateGroups is set:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Express/Review.php:216
```

I searched for `setShippingRateGroups()` and `Shipping_Rate_Groups`

This value is somewhere loaded and set implicit. Good luck with the debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Even though it had nothing to do with the actual problem, it did point me in a right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that the USPS extension is based on their Dimensional shipping extension. Does the extension allow you to set up shipping package/box sizes? Is there a possibility that your products are dimensionally larger than the box(es) you have setup, or that you haven't set up any boxes yet? We ran into that issue with a similar extension.

Otherwise, it might be worth looking at your log files to see if Magento is "gracefully" swallowing an exception and trying to continue processing the request.

Comment: As far as I can tell the extension simply adds the new/changed shipping options (Standard instead of Parcel, etc.). But anyhow, I don't think any of my products are larger than the box sizes - I set it up to use "Priority Flat Rate Box"

Comment: Sorry, that was the best guess I had. Answer updated.